# Custom "authentication_form" does not apply bootstrap CSS

Tags: python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, django-1.11

I'm attempting to apply bootstrap to a django login form. I have scoured google for hours and pretty much everyone is saying the same thing, which is to set the custom `authentication_form` in `urls.py`, override the username and password fields in custom login form and pass the class through the widget's `attrs` parameter. I have done this but django still isn't applying the form-control class to my input fields. I'm not quite sure what is going wrong. The form still renders, but without applying the bootstrap styling.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView, 
    PasswordChangeView, PasswordChangeDoneView, \
    PasswordResetView, PasswordResetDoneView, 
    PasswordResetConfirmView, PasswordResetCompleteView

from account.forms import LoginForm
from account.views import dashboard

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), {'authentication_form': 
        LoginForm}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url(r'^password-change/$', PasswordChangeView.as_view(), 
        name='password_change'),
    url(r'^password-change/done/$', PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), 
        name='password_change_done'),
    url(r'^password-reset/$', PasswordResetView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password-reset/done/$', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^password-reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-
        Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^password-reset/complete/$', 
        PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.forms import CharField, TextInput, PasswordInput


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-
    control'}))
password = CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-
    control'}))
```

views.py

```
@login_required(
    redirect_field_name=reverse_lazy('login'),
    login_url=reverse_lazy('login'))
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 
        'dashboard'})
```

[login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itzyH.png)

Comment: where is the form validation in views.py? you need to check if the form is valid and then save the data.

Comment: @hasTheFranz I had that in there at one point, but took it out when trying to fix the styling issue

Comment: yeah get it back in. Without that your form will never work. Is the form even showing up in the template? you use `{{form}}` in the template?

Comment: @hansTheFranz I was mistaken. One of the routes I went down was to define a custom view that extended `django.views.generic.FormView` in views.py. The custom view had overridden form_valid. Most of the examples I saw for the LoginForm didn't implement is_valid. I don't understand how that is going to cause the style class to be added to the rendered form.

Comment: @hansTheFranz yeah the form is displaying. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: oh man im so sorry I completely misread your question I thought your problem is that your form is not validating. Your title is a bit misleading. So the best thing to do when you want to style is using widget tweaks.

Comment: @hansTheFranz I updated the title to reflect the topic better. It's my first question :) So this is for my final project for my summer Internet Programming class and I wanted to eliminate using dependencies outside of django (except for bootstrap which is accessed through CDN) so that my project is pretty much self-contained.

Comment: I will post an answer and hope that it fits your needs but I'm to tired right now since its 3:30 am where I live.if it does not work I will help you tomorrow. Or probably somebody will already have fixed this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my templates I use [Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks)

```
<form method='POST' action="/" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 {% load widget_tweaks %}
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.first_name |add_class:"customCSS1 customCSS2" }}
 {{ form.second_name |add_class:"form-control customCSS4" }}
</form>
{{ form.media.js }}
```

with this plugin you can style the form as you wish. You could add your `form-control` class or use a personal CSS class like

```
.customCSS1{
  width60%;
  border-radius:5px;
 }
```