# How to customize html produced by django form fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I am writing a form in Django (Django 1.11.2, python 3.5.3). I am unhappy with html it produces - I found better input element in some external library.

I have forms.py:

```
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    fromTime = forms.DateField(label="Od")
    toTime = forms.DateField(label="Do")
```

and html template:

```
<form action="/report/selectDocument" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>{{ form.as_table }}</table>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Which together produces:

```
<input type="text" name="fromTime" required id="id_fromTime" />
....
<input type="text" name="toTime" required id="id_toTime" />
```

While I would like to get:

```
<input data-dependent-validation='{"from": "date-to", "prop": "max"}' type="date" id="fromTime" placeholder="RRRR-MM-DD" />
<input data-dependent-validation='{"from": "date-from", "prop": "min"}' type="date" id="toTime"   placeholder="RRRR-MM-DD" />
```

**How to tell django to produce such html for form fields?** Change can be global, but I would prefer it to be per-field.

The changes look small, but I want to achieve something like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/KEfEX/37/ I can hardcode custom input elements, but I would prefer to use django forms. Forms however produce quite poor date input - user must write the date using keyboard instead of selecting with mouse (I know about `widget=forms.SelectDateWidget()`, but solution from fiddle is even better).

Comment: So you can use [widget tweaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023799/custom-authentication-form-does-not-apply-bootstrap-css/45023977#45023977) to give your form css classes. With those you can style the form. For placeholder set attributes in forms.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set additional attributes for form field widget using [attrs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) parameter.

```
fromTime = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={
    'data-dependent-validation': '{"from": "date-to", "prop": "max"}',
    'placeholder': 'RRRR-MM-DD'
}))
```

Comment: this works. It even allows to override `type="text"` into `type="date"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in the `__init__` method like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['fromTime'].widget.attrs({
        'placeholder': "RRRR-MM-DD",
        'data-dependent-validation': '{"from": "date-to", "prop": "max"}'
    })
    self.fields['toTime'].widget.attrs({
        'placeholder': "RRRR-MM-DD",
        'data-dependent-validation': '{"from": "date-from", "prop": "min"}'
    })
```